# get result of the sqlite query as image

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, ios6

I was wondering if you can get a screenshot of the result of your query from database.
ie : It should take a snapshot(like desktop-print/screen) of the response of the query ,the way it looks on the database with columns and fields.

Result would be a .png format or any valid format to display the same on iPad.
Is it possible ?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Perhaps there is some way of scripting your database application and taking screenshots of it. what application are you wanting to get screen shots of?

Comment: like the sqlite library? You'd need to fetch your queries into a UI of your creation, render it offscreen, and save the render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me you can just run your database on browser (firefox -> tools ->sqlitemanager ->import your file), then you can run the required query and get the table required. Now you can simply take the screen shot and put that on image view were ever you want.

Please notify if it works..:)